# PHPでMySQLから取ってきた値が空になる

Tags: php, mysql

現在`PHP`で`MySQL`から値を取得しようとしているのですが、値が空になってしまいます。
サーバがローカルサーバを使っているので、それが原因かなと個人的に思っているのですが、関係はあるでしょうか？
ちなみに下記のコードのSQL文を`phpMyAdmin`上で試してみると期待通りの結果が返ってきました。
どなたか分かる方がいればどこが違うのか教えていただきたいです。すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

```
class Test{

    public function getData(){

        $mysqli = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass);

        if ($mysqli -> connect_errno) {
            echo $mysqli -> connect_error;
            exit();
        }

        $mysqli -> select_db('test');
        $mysqli -> set_charset("utf-8");

        $query = "SELECT * FROM word WHERE num = " .$this -> getNum();
        $result = $mysqli -> query($query);

        if (!$result) {
            $mysqli -> close();
            exit();
        }

        $data = array();
        while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
            array_push($data, $row);
        }

        $result -> free();
        $mysqli -> close();

        return $data;
    }
}

$test = new Test();
$data = $test -> getData(); 

foreach ($data as $value) {
    var_dump($value['word']);
}
```

---追記---

結果が空になる原因が多分分かったと思います。
`SELECT`文でint型の値を取得すると、出力結果に?と表示されました。
そして文字列型の値を取得すると、出力結果は空でした。
なので文字コード（？）とかそういったものが原因なのではないかと思います。
仮に`SELECT * FROM word`としてデータを全て取得すると、int型の値だけ?になりました。（なぜ出力結果がハテナになるのかもわかりませんが......）
PHPの文字コードなどの設定もしてみたのですが、依然思った結果が得られていません。
どうすればよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: 「出力結果は空」だったのを、どのように確認されましたでしょうか？上のコードだと 結果を return しているところまでの記載だったので。。。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。現在iOSとPHPを連携させており、出力結果はiOSのログで確認しました。

Comment: int 型のデータで ? と表示されているとのことなので、文字コードの問題ではない気がしています。サーバーからのレスポンスは json  形式でしょうか？

Comment: 文字コードの問題ではないのですね。レスポンスはjsonではありません。
一通りの流れのコードを追記しました。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 追記されたコードの最後で `$word['word']` を取得していますが、`$data` や `$word` は一行の各列ではなく、各行の配列になるはずです。クエリ結果の確認も兼ねて、 `var_dump($data)` を実行してみてください。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。上記のコードを編集し、一番下のforeachでvar_dumpをしたところ、[string(1) "?"
string(2) "??"
string(2) "??"
]
という結果が返ってきました。
今データベースのword列には3つ値があり、文字数も順番に1文字、2文字、2文字となっており、上の出力結果と同じです。ただ、なぜ??になっているのでしょうか？

Comment: @kojianu さん、 var_dump($value) → [string(1) "?" string(2) "??" string(2) "??" ] の状況であれば、文字コードの問題だと思います。記載のコードを変更されて確認していらっしゃる場合は、こちらの質問に記載されているコードも随時更新されたほうがよいと思いますよ。

Comment: @terutosiya さん、解決することができました。やはり文字コードの問題でした。下に自分で回答しました。この度は誠にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

問題が解決できました。

http://kuroanco.hateblo.jp/entry/20130903/1378199119

上記のサイトにあるように

```
$db->query("set names utf8");
```

と書いてあげると、出力結果が?になる問題と、SELECT文で条件を指定した時に出力結果が空になる問題が同時に解決されました。
ご回答くださった皆様、誠にありがとうございました。

Comment: プログラム言語側、クライアントライブラリ、DB側すべての文字エンコーディングが適切に設定されていないと、SQLインジェクション脆弱性が生じる場合があります。`SET NAMES`はMySQLのクライアントライブラリ内部の状態を更新しないため、その原因の一つとなります。元の質問の症状がなぜ生じているかは(情報が不足しており)わからないのですが、「`SET NAMES`で直った」というのは問題がまだ残っている状態なので、そのままの状態ではリリースされないよう強くお勧めします。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。まだ問題は残ったままなのですね。SQLインジェクション対策後にリリースしたいと思います。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

直接の回答でなくて恐縮ですが、
[PHPのsprintfによるSQL組み立てで脆弱性が生じる例](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/9484)
[PHP での SQL インジェクション対策はどのように行いますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/5053)
この辺を参考にクエリの作成方法を見直した方が良いように思います。

本題としては、
・各変数（$server, $user, $pass）に入っている値が正しいか
・DBに接続できているか
・処理がどこまで実行されているか
あたりの確認からでしょうか。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。セキュリティ対策も調べてみようと思います。DBには接続できており、一応最後まで処理は行われています。

Answer (score 1):

私ならMySQLのクエリログを、確認しますね。
phpMyAdminの時とPHPで書いた時と比較してみては、どうでしょうか。
（むかーしむかし。私は、phpMyAdminで見ていたDBが間違っていた(USE先が違う)とか。接続先が間違っていた(ログが出なかった)というケアレスミスを、やらかしたことがあります）

-- 訂正 --
「追記」の内容からすると。行は取得できているようなので。
この確認作業は、おそらく不要です。（確認して損はありませんが有益かどうかというと疑問です）

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。クエリログを取って確認してみたいと思います。

Comment: 訂正の件了解しました。ありがとうございます。